# django: Invalid block tag on line 8: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Please help with the error I am getting following along a django book.The errors states: "Invalid block tag on line 8: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?". Attached is the image. Thanks
[django webpage error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myEg9.png)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %} 

{% block content %} 
{% if user.is_authenticated %} 
    Hi {{user.username}}!
    <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `endblock`. You don't need to add `content`

```
{% endblock %}
```

not

```
{% endblock content %}
```

The same goes for the title.

Comment: After removing 'content' and 'title' from the code as you instructed, I now get : ''block' tag takes only one argument" Error.

Comment: Update the question with the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Always use the same blocks that are used in base.html
try this:
base.html`{% block content %} {% endblock %}`

Inherited Template:`{% block content %} write code  here {% endblock %}`

Comment: Thanks Guys. Your solutions worked, my code is now running.

Answer (score 0):

Use **{% endblock %}** instead of {% endblock content %} or {% endblock title %}.